# DT collapse all row groups by default

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am trying to make all row groups in a datatable collapse by default,

my current implementation:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("my_table")))

callback_js <- JS(
  "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
  "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
  "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
  "});"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = 'RowGroup',
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 3), pageLength = 20),
      callback = callback_js,
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Results:

[image]

My desired output:

**All row groups should be collapsed at initial** (at 1st time table is rendered), I cannot found any solutions existed yet

Update (24 Mar 2021):

Thanks to @thothal, now the table is collapse at init, but in case of multiple DT at different tabs, the first table will expand unintended, when navigate back and forth

Code to reproduce:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1", dataTableOutput("my_table")),
      tabPanel("table2", dataTableOutput("my_table2"))
    )
  ))

callback_js <- JS(
  "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
  "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
  "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
  "});",
  "table.on('init', () => $('.dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = 'RowGroup',
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 3), pageLength = 20),
      callback = callback_js,
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  output$my_table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = 'RowGroup',
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 3), pageLength = 20),
      callback = callback_js,
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/  at the end it says: "No option to expand / collapse a group"

Comment: @PatrickBormann yes, but I am wishing some JS experts could teach me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution for multiple DTs, we need to specify which tables to trigger 'click' event. Since DT are lazy render, when other DT render, it remove hidden class for previous table

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1", dataTableOutput("my_table")),
      tabPanel("table2", dataTableOutput("my_table2"))
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = 'RowGroup',
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 3), pageLength = 20),
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
        "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
        "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
        "});",
        "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
      ),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  output$my_table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = 'RowGroup',
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 3), pageLength = 20),
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
        "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
        "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
        "});",
        "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table2 .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
      ),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapt your `callback` as follows:

```
callback_js <- JS(
   "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
   "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
   "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
   "});",
   "table.on('init', () => $('.dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
)
```

This will trigger all click events once the table is set up.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however it only works for 1 single DT, for multiple DTs, other DT still expanded unintentionally, I have updated the post

Comment: This is because the click event for the rows is triggered twice for the first table. You have a couple of options: either adapt your target such that it targets the rows only of the table in question, run the fold code directly, i.e. not using trigger (which does a toggle) or find an event which fires when all tables are fully loaded.

Comment: @thothal Thanks. This answer has helped me as well but I have a small issue. If the first row group contains more than pageLength, then you can't see other collapsed rowgroups. You'd have to go to the page where the first group ends. FOr example, say in the above example, the rowgroup 160 has 45 rows. pageLength is 20. In the first page, you would only be able to see the first 20 collapsed rows of 160. To see the collapsed the next row groups(108, 258), you'd have to go to the third page since 46th rowfalls in the 3rd page. Is there any way I can have all rowgroups collapsed in the first page?