# Expandable/Collapsible rows for datatable in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables

I'm trying to build something like a sales report where country-level sales aggregate to regional level and can be seen through expand/collapse button at the regional rows. For example if I have a table like:
[image]

Then I want a resulting starting table to be

[image]

and i can click on a button next to "North America" to see the country-level details below.

It seems like the only way to do it in Shiny is through datatable and manipulating the callback functions, which require quite a bit of javascript knowledge (that I don't have). I did find another answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56599838) that got me started. But there are still some key differences that I wasn't able to figure out (for example, showing both top-level label AND the top-level sales data at the same time, as opposed to only showing the top-level label in the other answer).

Could anyone give some advice on how to go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want child tables, see here :<https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html>.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66774002/19789313